# Finding missing words in string

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to solve a problem of finding missing words in a string.

For example:
**Input**
`String 1 = "I love programming, pizza, coke and chips";`
`String 2 = "I programming, chips";`
**Required Output**
`Missing words = "love pizza coke";`

> **Note**: the order of output has to be same (this is where I am messing up)

what I have so far, but I am getting wrong results.

```
public static List<String> findWord(String s, String t) {
    HashSet<String> missingWords = new HashSet<>();
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (!t.contains(words[i])) {
            missingWords.add(words[i]);
        }
    }
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str: missingWords) {
        ans.add(str);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: why do you create an `ArrayList`? why isn't `missingWords` sufficient?

Comment: cause it is a set and I need to return list

Comment: "I am getting wrong results" is not sufficient. Show us the results you're getting. The fastest way to find your error is to use your debugger. It's a powerful tool. If you don't know how to use it, take the time *right now* to learn. You can thank me later.

Comment: You can not split by space, you may have double cheese pizza  or simple pizza. Hashset won't work in same case.

Comment: What about `and` word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by splitting both input strings, stripping off punctuation, and then walking down each array of words, in the original order.  When encountering a match, both lists advance.  When there is no match, the original list advances, but the second list does not, and we also record the original word as not having found a match.

The key point here is that we use an `ArrayList`, which maintains insertion order, while traversing.

```
String input = "I love programming, pizza, coke and chips";
String other = "I programming, chips";
String[] parts = input.replaceAll("[,.;-]", "").split("\\s");
String[] otherparts = other.replaceAll("[,.;-]", "").split("\\s");
List<String> missing = new ArrayList<>();
int pnt = 0;
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    if (parts[i].equals(otherparts[pnt])) {
        ++pnt;
    }
    else {
        missing.add(parts[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(missing.toArray()));

[I, love, programming, pizza, coke, and, chips]
[love, pizza, coke, and]
```

### Demo

Demo added for informational purposes only.  Do not rely on it for production use.

Comment: That's the way to do it ;-)  Although you may want to check for duplicate missing values e.g. `String input = "I love love programming, pizza, coke and chips";`

Comment: @ScaryWombat And what would be the string in the comparison in this case?

Comment: `String input = "I love programming, love pizza, coke and chips";
        String other = "I programming, chips";`  `[I, love, programming, love, pizza, coke, and, chips]
[love, love, pizza, coke, and]` - should it print twice?

Comment: Got you, yeah, not clear.  We could add the output from my code into a `LinkedHashSet`, which would remove duplicates but preserve insertion order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen **NOT CORRECT SOLUTION**, test case `other = "chips, programming I"` returns incorrect result.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik You are interpreting the OP differently than I did.  Using your test case, I report only `chips` as matching, because my algorithm balks until the first word `chips` finds a match.  That doesn't happen until the very _last_ word in the input.  In other words, I assume that the OP wants to also maintain ordering in the data.

Answer (score 0):

> HashSet is an un-ordered collection and its not possible to store element in any order, but if you have to access elements of HashSet in sorted order then you can first convert it to List and then sort it out

```
HashSet<String> missingWords = new HashSet<>();
...
missingWords.add(words[i]);// <== the order here is correct
...
for(String str: missingWords){// <== the order here is incorrect
   ans.add(str);
}
```

Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: wait, i didn't get that?

Comment: `missingWords` is un-ordered so when you loop and add it into List it will not make sure the order is correct.

Comment: When I debug your work, I saw the `missingWords.add(words[i]);` is correct, each word is added correctly into `missingWords`, but when `for(String str: missingWords)` the order is messed up. Do you get it?

Comment: `Set<String> missingWords = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple problem.

1. Split both string with words using RegExp: `\W+`
2. Expected words put into `HashSet`: unique not ordered
3. Existed words put into `ArrayList`: not unique ordered
4. Remove all words from the `List` that not contain in `Set`: `removeAll()`

Demo:

```
public static List<String> findMissingWords(String str, String expectedWords) {
    Set<String> expected = Arrays.stream(expectedWords.split("\\W+")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    List<String> existed = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\W+")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    existed.removeAll(expected);
    return existed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the order of insertion, you should use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`.

```
String s = "I love programming, pizza, coke and chips";
        String t = "I programming, chips";

         LinkedHashSet<String> missingWords = new LinkedHashSet<>(); //<---to maintain the order
            String[] words = s.split(" ");
            for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (!t.contains(words[i])) {
                    missingWords.add(words[i].replaceAll(",", "")); //<---add without comma
                }
            }
            List<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String str: missingWords) {
                ans.add(str);
            }

            System.out.println(ans);
```

> Output:[love, pizza, coke, and]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String s = "I love programming, pizza, coke and chips";
    String t = "I programming, chips";
    
    String[] firstWord = s.replaceAll(",","").split("\\s+");
    String[] secondWord = t.replaceAll(",","").split("\\s+");
    ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(firstWord));
    ArrayList<String> temp3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(firstWord));
    ArrayList<String> temp2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(secondWord));
    
    ArrayList<String> finals = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    finals.addAll(missingWords(temp1, temp2));
    finals.addAll(missingWords(temp2, temp3));
    
    System.out.println(finals);
 }
 
 static ArrayList<String> missingWords(ArrayList<String> str1, ArrayList<String> str2) {

     str1.removeAll(str2);
     
     return str1;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

split the two strings with space separator, then use the in_array function